# UITableView with dynamic sections and custom cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

My data structor looks like this:

Inside an `NSArray` I have a few objects from different classes. How the array looks like if something like this:

Let's say `myArray` has 3 `objectA`s. Each `objectA` and an `NSArry` that has `objectB`s

Now at runtime I do not know the array counts.

My `UITableView` displays one `objectA` per section. Each section has 1 row. Unless my `objectA` has an NSArray of `objectB`s with a count of greater than 0.

So the `UITableView` would look like this if all my `objectA`'s has no arrays of `objectB's` in them.

```
Section 1: Row 1: `objectA instance
Section 2: Row 1: `objectA instance
Section 3: Row 1: `objectA instance
```

Lets say the 3rd `objectA` has an array of `objectB`'s with a count of 1. My `UITableView` would look like this:

```
Section 1: Row 1: `objectA instance
Section 2: Row 1: `objectA instance
Section 3: Row 1: `objectA instance
Section 3: Row 2: `objectB instance
```

Now I am using two different `UITableViewCell`s for each `object` so `objectA` would use `CustomCell1` and `objectB` would use `CustomCell2`

Here is where I am getting stuck - I need to return the correct cell to the correct section / row.

So I made sure my `UITableView` knows what to expect.

I wrote the methods like so:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ObjectA *objectA = self.myArray[section];

    return [objectA.objectBArray count] +1;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.myArra count];
}
```

So `numberOfRowsInSection` takes a look at the `objectB`s array and returns its count + 1 so that even if its 0 there is always one row. (I need at least one row for objectA in the current section.

`numberOfSectionsInTableView` is straight forward - one section for each `objectA` in `self.myArray`

This seems to do exactly as I need.

I then got stuck on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

This is how far I got:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CustomCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
        CustomCell2 *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];


        ObjectA *objectA = self.myArray[indexPath.section]; //Each section has one ObjectA. 

        //Make sure we have some objectB's to display first 
        if ([objectA. objectBArray count] > 0){
            ObjectB *objectb = (ObjectB*) objectA.objectB[indexPath.row]; 

          //if the current section (section 3) has a indexPath 0 already 
            // index path 1 would have the first objectB 

        }

        cell1.objectA = objectA;
        cell2.objectB = objectB;

      //Now return the correct cell for the current section / index path
    }
```

So I need to check if the current section already has valid cell1 object if it does I then need to return cell2 to the second or third row. for `objectB` As row one must always have a cell1.

I know I am almost there. I just can't figure out how to return the correct cell.

**Update**

So the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is only being called three times. Here is what I did in `numberOfRowsInSection` method to make sure it returns the right number of rows:

```
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ObjectA *objectA = self.myArray[section];
    NSLog (@"Section:%ld", (long)section);
    NSLog(@"Returning %ld", (long)[objectA.objectBArray count]+1);


    return [objectA.objectBArray count] +1;
}
```

My console shows this:

```
2014-07-16 19:36:17.488 App[15473:60b] Section:2
2014-07-16 19:36:17.488 App[15473:60b] Returning 2
2014-07-16 19:36:18.128 App[15473:60b] Section:0
2014-07-16 19:36:18.128 App[15473:60b] Returning 1
2014-07-16 19:36:19.063 App[15473:60b] Section:1
2014-07-16 19:36:19.063 App[15473:60b] Returning 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will always only be one `objectA` in each section then you can test if your `indexPath.row` is anything larger then zero (not the first row).

See if this does the trick:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
    CustomCell2 *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];

    ObjectA *objectA = self.myArray[indexPath.section]; //Each section has one ObjectA.
    cell1.objectA = objectA;

    //Check if not first row and objectB's exist
    if (indexPath.row > 0 && [objectA. objectBArray count] > 0){
        ObjectB *objectb = (ObjectB*) objectA.objectB[indexPath.row];
        cell2.objectB = objectB;
        return cell2;
    }

    return cell1;
}
```

Comment: That's actually pretty simple. Should have gotten that. I'll test now to see if thats what I need. Thanks bud!

Comment: I've tried the code you've given me, however the if statement is never executed. Even when a section has more than one row. Something I am doing in numberOfRows is wrong maybe?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the sub array.  Run `NSLog(@"Section: %d, Object B Count: %d", indexPath.section, [objectA.objectBArray count]);` to see what count your getting.

Comment: Just done that - I put the logs in the numberOfRows method and each section is showing correctly. numberOfRowsInSection returns 2 for section 2 - which is correct. and 1 for other sections. Logging cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called 3 times though (One for each section)

Comment: Interesting, `numberOfRowsInSection` returns the correct number of rows per section but the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only being called once for each section?  I'm not sure what would cause that to happen.

Comment: It is interesting. I have updated my question on exactly what my logs show. Maybe I am doing something silly somewhere?

Comment: I tried now to just return a static number for each section. I just put "return 4" in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath is called 5 times. Index is always 0. But the table view shows 3 sections with 4 rows each. Something is not right!

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct as you did help me fix the original issue. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found the answer to the second part as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the second issue I was having. After setting breakpoints in my view controller - I noticed my tableView was already loading cells before my call to [self.tableView reloadData];

Not sure why that was happening so a quick nil-check in my rows for items method solved the issue:

if the  main array had no objects - return 0. If it did - return objectBArray count + 1; Now the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called the correct number of times.